# retrieve data from the database and load the data into the table using jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

```
              <!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Material Design for Bootstrap</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/mdb-favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mdb.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
src="js/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Main Navigation-->
        <header>

            <!--Navbar-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark indigo">

                <!-- Additional container -->
                <div class="container">

                    <!-- Navbar brand -->
                    <!--        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>-->

                    <!-- Collapse button -->
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#basicExampleNav"
                            aria-controls="basicExampleNav"
aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Collapsible content -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
id="basicExampleNav">

                        <!-- Links -->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>


                            <!-- Dropdown -->
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <!--              <a class="nav-link
dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
aria-haspopup="true"

aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>-->
                                <!--              <div
class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary"
aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                                <a
class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                                <a
class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                                <a
class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                              </div>-->
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <!-- Links -->

                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto">

                                <input class="form-control"
id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="search">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-white
btn-" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>

                            </div>


                    </div>

                    <!-- Collapsible content -->

                </div>
                <!-- Additional container -->

            </nav>

            <h2 class='mb-3'>INDENT DETAILS</h2>

            <!--<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">EMPLOYEENAME</div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">INDENTNO</div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">INDENTSHORTDES</div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">INDENTDATE
                    </div>
            </div>

            </div>-->
            <div class="container">
                <table id ="table" data-toggle="table" class="tabletable-striped table-hover display" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th
data-field="EMPLOYEECODE"><span>EMPLOYEECODE</span></th>
                            <th
data-field="INDENTDATE"><span>INDENTDATE</span></th>
                            <th
data-field="INDENTNO"><span>INDENTNO</span></th>

                            <th
data-field="INDENTSHORTDES"><span>INDENTSHORTDES</span></th>
                            <th
data-field="REGISTEREDDATE"><span>REGISTEREDDATE</span></th>
                            <th
data-field="LINEITEMCODE"><span>LINEITEMCODE</span></th>
<!--                            <th>
                                <button type="button" class=
"btn-blue btn-primary btn-sm">View details</button>
                            </th>-->

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

            <!--/.Navbar-->

        </header>
        <!--Main Navigation-->

        <!--Main layout-->
        <main class="mt-5">

            <!--Main container-->
            <div class="container">

                <!--Grid row-->
                <div class="row">

                    <!--Grid column-->
                    <div class="col-md-7 mb-4">

                        <div class="view overlay z-depth-1-half">
                            <img
src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(70).jpg"
                                 class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <div class="mask rgba-white-light"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 mb-4">

                        <h2>INDENT DETAILS</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <p>To view indent details please go to search
option and give your <br>Employee ID and click to <b>VIEW INDENTS</b>
</p>
                        <!--<a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/"
class="btn btn-indigo">Get it now!</a>-->

                    </div>
                    <!--Grid column-->

                </div>
                <!--Grid row-->

                <!--Grid row-->
                <div class="row">

                    <!--Grid column-->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">

                        <!--Card-->
                        <div class="card">

                            <!--Card image-->
                            <div class="view overlay">
                                <img
                                    src="images/image6.jpg"
class="card-img-top"
                                    alt="">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <!--Card content-->


                        </div>
                        <!--/.Card-->

                    </div>
                    <!--Grid column-->

                    <!--Grid column-->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">

                        <!--Card-->
                        <div class="card">

                            <!--Card image-->
                            <div class="view overlay">
                                <img src=".jpg"
                                     class="card-img-top"
                                     alt="">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="view overlay">
                                <img src="" class="card-img-top"
                                     alt="">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="page-footer font-small indigo pt-4 mt-4">
            <div class="container text-center text-md-left">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
                        <p>Designed & Developed by DISM, ISRO
Headquarters, Antariksh Bhavan, New BEL Road Bangalore- 560094</p>

                    </div>
                    <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:
                <a
href="https://mdbootstrap.com/bootstrap-tutorial/">MDBootstrap.com</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <button>click</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {


        $.ajax({
                    //url: 'http://localhost:8080/indentDetails/array.json',
                    url: 'coinsIndentsServlet?empid=TR10472',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 2500,
                    "columns": [

                {"data": "EMPLOYEECODE"},
                {"data":"   INDENTDATE"},
                {"data":"   INDENTNO"},
                {"data":"   INDENTSHORTDES"},
                {"data":"   REGISTEREDDATE"},
                {"data":"   LINEITEMCODE"}

                    ],
                    success: function (result)
                    {

                        console.log('complete with success and
data:', result.indents);
                        $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', result.indents);
//                        $('#table tbody tr').each(function(){
//                            s=$('<span style=" left:10px;
right:30px; top:10px; bottom:10px">View details</span>');
//                            s.click(function(e){
//                                e.stopPropgation();
//                                alert('clicked');
//
//                            });
//                            $(this).append(s);
//                        });
                    }



            });


//            $('#table-anexo').DataTable({
//                "ajax":'coinsIndentsServlet'
//            });
        });

        </script>
    </body>
        </html>
```

i have created an application where an employee can see his all details once he gives his  employeeid into search field .
i have tired jquery and materialdesign bootstrap  for this application i dont know what is issue , please suggest an answer for this .
when an client wants to see his details he can just give an employeeid into the search placeholder and they can see the data into the table .
here i am using bootstrap - JQuery
i am trying to load the table with data from database using employeeID, when iam giving an employeeid into the search placeholder automatically table should be loaded with that particular employee details.

Comment: post the relevant code for the issue not all the code in your page please

Comment: can you help out

Comment: please be more specific by showing all the relevant code (not only HTML)

Comment: @jyothikachapur have you seen my answer below?

Comment: iam using servlet here iam not using php can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to show instant results from the value of an input via AJAX

**HTML**

```
 <form method='post'>
 <input type='text' id='search'>
 </form>
 <div id='mydiv'></div>
```

**JS** using jQuery 3.4.1

```
 $(document).ready(function() { // Wait until document has loaded
 function load_data(query) { // Begin function to load data from query
 $.ajax({
 url:"myserverfile.php", // Link to PHP file
 method:"POST",
 data:{query:query},
 success:function(data){
 $('#mydiv').html(data); // Show data in div
 }
 });
 }
 $('#search').keyup(function() { // Await keyboard entry on input
 var search = $(this).val(); // Get value of input on keyboard entry
 load_data(search); // Load the data from value of input
 });
 });
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST["query"])) {
 require_once('db.php'); // Your SQL connection file 
 $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["query"]); // Sanitize input
 $select = mysqli_query($con,"select * from table where id like '%".$query."%'"); // Selecting the primary id key from the table (or any unique value)
 if (mysqli_num_rows($select)> 0) { // If result
 $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
 print_r($rows); // This prints an array, for nicer output create a while loop and specify indexes from the table.
 } else {
 echo "no data"; 
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Tested on a working server.

Comment: iam not using php here , iam using servlet how to load the data using servlet